# Correct way to write a set with a condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory

**Introduction.** Let's consider a sequence of length $n$, i.e. $A=(a_k)_{k=1}^{n}$. Within that sequence, a (general) subsequence of length $m$, and starting at position $i$, can be defined as $A_{i}=(a_k)_{k=i}^{i+m-1}$. Also, for the rest of my question, the subsequence length $m$ is fixed and constant, for any subsequence.

Now, I would like to define a set $D_{i}$ containing all the Euclidean distances among a specific (chosen) subsequence $A_{i}=(a_k)_{k=i}^{i+m-1}$ (with "chosen" I refer to the fact that we choose a specific value for the index $i$) and all the other subsequences $A_{j}=(a_k)_{k=j}^{j+m-1}$ within the same sequence, with varying $j$, but with the condition that the two subsequences in my calculation of distance, cannot overlap, i.e. $\left| i-j \right| \geq m$.

I was thinking about writing my set $D_{i}$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
D_{i} = 
\left\{ 
\left\lVert A_{i}-A_{j} \right\rVert_{2} 
\, \colon \,
\left| i-j \right| \geq m
\right\}
\end{equation}
However, I should probabily add something like "$\forall j$", since the index $i$ is fixed (I am indeed focusing on all the distances from the subsequence $A_{i}$), while $j$ varies. Nevertheless, I do not think I can use $j=1,2,3,...$ since some of those $j$ would not satisfy the $\left| i-j \right| \geq m$ condition. Also, as mentioned before, the subsequence length $m$ is fixed and constant, for any subsequence, both for $A_{i}$ and for $A_{j}$.

**Question.** Do you have any suggestion to correctly write $D_{i}$, in such a way that it represents what I tried to explain?

Comment: You could add "$\text{and } 1\le j \le n+1-m$" in the set. You don't need a quantifier here.

Comment: Thanks @Gribouillos! Yes, by writing: \begin{equation}
D_{i} = 
\left\{ 
\left\lVert A_{i}-A_{j} \right\rVert_{2} 
\, \colon \,
\left| i-j \right| \geq m \, \land 1 \leq j \leq n+1-m
\right\}
\end{equation}, I would interpret that $j$ varies from $1$ to $n+1-m$ and, at the same time, the non-overlap condition is respected. Did I interpret it correctly? Just two small notes: (1) should I add something related to the index $i$, to say that it is fixed? (2) I don't know what you mean with the word "quantifier"... :-) obviously, if you want to write all as an answer I would accept it! :-)

Comment: You don't need to add anything about $i$ because the index in $D_i$ shows that the set depends from a previously mentioned integer $i$. A quantifier is either $\forall$ or $\exists$

Comment: Ah OK! Yes, great! (Yes, sorry, about the quantifier, I was thinking about something else..) :-)